# parsing json from angular into servlets

Tags: java, json, http, post, servlets

I developed an application in angular which contain forms. And sent the data in the form of json using http post, and want to read those values in servlets and display. Can anyone please suggest me the solution.

```
onSubmit() {
let enteredDetails = {
  ename: this.name,
  email: this.email,
  phoneNo: this.phoneNo
}
let contactDetails = JSON.stringify(enteredDetails);
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/registerationapp/ins', contactDetails);
```

The json object that is created is in this form.
    {"ename":"vardhan","email":"abcd@gmail.com","phoneNo":"9876543210"}

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what do you mean by "read those values in servlets and display"?

Comment: i want to get "entered  values" from angular and wanted store these values in database by using servlets program.And i want code of servlets to get these values.

Comment: Why do you insist that it should be a "servlet"? Do you already have a java application with other servlets? You seem to ask several questions: how to make a java servlet application, how to process JSON in java, how to connect to a database, how to map an object to a database table, etc. Please try to be specific in which part you are focusing on in the question. Consider asking several questions for the different parts. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for suggestions in how to ask a good question.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) post for parsing `json` data .

Comment: I want only code to get these angular form values into servlets.